# Can I put WiFi access points between my modem and router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, modem

I'm attempting to wire a house for internet that's a bit too far away from a road with the cable line (about 250 yards across a field). The local ISP won't run a cable to the house, but they are willing to drop a cable from a pole on the road. My plan is to put the modem and a WiFi access point on a pole in the neighbor's yard (with their permission) which would have a directional antenna pointing towards the house. The house would have a matching directional antenna connected to another access point which would be plugged into the router inside the house:

```
modem <-ethernet-> access point <-WiFi-> access point <-ethernet-> router
```

My question is two-fold:

1. Would this even work? I've never tried putting anything between the modem and the router before. I'm not sure if it would interfere with the router connecting to the modem.
2. Is there a better way to do this? I'm trying to avoid digging a trench through the neighbor's property, as that is expensive, disruptive, and a huge pain to maintain if something happened to the cable.

Comment: This can work, but my main question is how you are going to power the modem and access point at the pole? Do you have a weather proof enclosure for them? I suppose you could install a small solar panel with battery, that's if you can do this without permission from whatever utility company owns the pole.

Comment: To clarify, the pole this will be mounted on isn't the telephone pole on the side of the road. I'm going to put a wooden post up for this.

Comment: As for power, this is something I need to work out with the local co-op. I know someone else in town who has a separate line from them that they pay a constant $10/month for to have a light on a post.

Comment: Doesn't sound bad, btw at the house you will need a wireless bridge, not access point. I would suggest the "Engenious eoc" line of products. They have very good transceivers, are built for outdoor use (weather-proof). And have built in directional antennas. I picked up two recently on eBay for $20 each.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work as written, but could walk with a minor tweek - you would need to change one end to an AP client. This solution assumes the modem is presenting the data on a raw Ethernet frame and not encapsulating it in a VLAN.

Answer (score 0):

This is entirely possible, IF you have the right equipment and there is access to power at the pole.

I have some experience with Ubiquiti Networks' [NanoBeam](https://www.ubnt.com/airmax/nanobeam-ac-gen2/) series , and with a pair of those, you can make a wireless network bridge from the modem on the pole to the router in your house. I have done this many times for customers, and it works flawlessly. I am sure there are other vendors too, but those I have no experience with.

Of course it requires some configuration and mounting the NanoBeams correctly, but once that is done, it will essentially work like you had it wired all the way.

As @Davidgo mentions, the two NanoBeams needs to be configured as one access point and another as a client/station.

modem <-ethernet-> NanoBeam (access point) <-WiFi-> NanoBeam (Station)<-ethernet-> router